# React Native IOS getting error Cannot read property 'startLoadWithResult' of null

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, telr

Hey there i am using payment integration lib `https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-telr-sdk` whenever try to run it it gives me this error therefore if anyone is facing this error please do help me on this.

[image]

Comment: did u get any solution?

Comment: I'm getting the same error while using this rich text editor library on iOS.
https://github.com/wxik/react-native-rich-editor

Did you ever find a fix? For me the call stack is alluding to something related to WebView.ios.js

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this, just updated react-native-webview to the latest version in my case it is 13.7.0 `npm i react-native-webview@latest`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This really helped me solve a similar problem i was having.